# How to find the direction of vector $ v(2)$ in this problem?

Tags: vectors

I'm having difficulties finding the direction for vector $v(2)$ in this problem:

Given the vectors $v(1) = <3,4>, v(2) = <1,1>$, and $v(3) = <2,7>$

What is the direction of vector $v(2)$?

Answer (score 0):

The direction of a vector $\vec{u}\neq \vec{0}$ is given by: $\dfrac{\vec{u}}{||\vec{u}||}$. Apply this definition for your $\vec{u} = <1,1>$